# Blame information not displayed in few SonarQube projects

Tags: sonarqube, git-blame

We are using SonarQube Version 5.6.3 and GitLab for version control. On certain projects, the blame entries are not displayed in SonarQube projects whereas it is shown on the rest of the projects. There seems to be no difference in the project settings and also no clues from the logs. This feature comes builtin with the SonarQube version.

How can we let SonarQube display the blame information for *all* projects?

Comment: Could you setup a minimal example project and try to reproduce the issue? Maybe only one git commit and only one file in the project with a minimal configuration. If you can reproduce, please edit your question and add the settings and logs.

Comment: Do you use the same build agent all the time? Did you inspect also the SonarQube log? You should also plan for an update to SonarQube 5.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify SCM settings for project:

- open project dashboard
- choose `Administration → General Settings → SCM`
- verify that `sonar.scm.disabled` is set to `false` or `Default` (where `Default: false`)

If you cannot modify settings on the server you can add `-Dsonar.scm.disabled=false` to scanner execution.

If SCM sensor is enabled then open logs from build and verify that:

- lines exist:

  ```
  [INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor
  [INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=19ms
  ```
- SCM directory with metadata exists (e.g. `.git`)